# Open "Speak Now" input method for EditText automatically

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have a EditText field. I want to start speech recognition input method when the user clicks on it. Instead of the keyboard the "Speak Now" speech recognition should start automatically without user interaction.

[image]

The speech recognition should be the primary input method for the edittext. Then the user has the fallback to the standard keyboard the the toggle on the screenshot.

How can I force to open speech input method when user clicks on an edittext?